# HTML - header banner for links not appearing

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, header, banner

I am learning web development and I am creating a practise website, however I am having some issues. I am trying give a background/banner to go behind the bit where the links to the other websites go. As far as I am aware I am correctly linking to the image and so on.

The code for the HTML:

```
<header role="banner" id="site_header">
<h1 role="heading"><a href="index.php" title="Sandwich Express">Sandwich Express</a></h1>
    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="event.html">Event Catering</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Code for CSS:

```
/* header */
#site_header {
    height: 188px;
    background: url(photos/headerbg.png) top repeat-x;
}
#site_header h1 {
    padding: 8px 0 0 21px;
    float: left;
}
#site_header h1 a {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    height: 173px;
    width: 176px;
    background: url(photos/logo.png);
    text-decoration: none;
}
#site_header nav {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#site_header nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 113px 0 0 6px;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}
#site_header nav ul li {
    font-family: "Century Gothic", "Gudea", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#site_header nav ul li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .3s ease;
   -o-transition: all .3s ease;
   -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
   -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;    
    text-decoration: none;
}
#site_header nav ul li a:hover, #site_header nav ul li .active {
    color: #900028
}
```

Any help would be great, I hope the CSS and html is correct.

Comment: can you post a link or screen shot, better still check your dev tools and see where the links are

Comment: What changes have you tried to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Sure looks like a path issue.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/04NR5ao.png - this is what i want it to look like. And, this is what it looks like https://cdn.mediacru.sh/A/ANE9fyMUfFVS.png , Also what are the dev tool?

Comment: See : http://jsfiddle.net/d7dnu4r1/1/ --- seems the image is not where you think it is ^^ (check the path).

Comment: https://cdn.mediacru.sh/s/soxe2Q-XBcJQ.png there is a picture of the banner thing I am using. Have I mistyped something and cannot see it?

Comment: As Paulie and sodawillow say, it looks like a path issue - the `photos/headerbg.png` needs to be relative to where your css file is sat (or if you put an initial slash `/photos/headerbg.png` then relative to the root of your site), so if you don't have a folder called photos in the same directory as your css file, then the path is wrong

Comment: @regb: Developer tools included in all modern browsers will help you a lot in troubleshooting your HTML, CSS and Javascript code as well as provide a quick way to analyze other people's websites or make small non-permanent changes on-the-fly. Here are the docs for [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) and [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). I heared even Internet Explorer has this feature nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that paths specified in CSS are relative to the CSS file, not the HTML file. So if your CSS is in a subdirectory `/css`, and the pictures are in a subdirectory `/photos` relative to the HTML file, your paths in CSS should start with `../photos`.

Comment: I have it in the right directory and still nothing :( . The photos are in website/css/photos/

Comment: Did you take a look at the Developer tools (devtools)? See my comment on your original post. You should be able to figure out what is going on that way. Which browser are you using/which browsers do you have installed?